# Correcting the text cursor in a UITextField when replacing its text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, nsnotificationcenter, uitextfielddelegate

I am implementing shortcut substitution for text typed into a `UITextField`.

For instance, if the text field already contains "a" and he types another "a" after it, I'd replace it with "ä". In another case, if he types "a", then "b", I'd replace it with "XYZ". And if the text contains two consecutive spaces, I like to replace them with a single space.

So, depending on what the user types, I might replace it with either a longer, a shorter, or a same-length text.

The *simple* way to do that is to implement the `[UITextFieldDelegate textField: shouldChangeCharactersInRange: ...` delegate function, assign the replacement text to `textField.text`, and return NO.

But this also requires adjusting the cursor position accordingly, and that's what I'm struggling with, a little.

I am handling this cursor positioning "by hand" currently. It's a bit ugly, and so I wonder if there is a more elegant solution. After all, all the code for handling the cursor position after replacing text (e.g. when selecting, then pasting) is already implemented in the `UITextField` code anyway. I just wonder if more of it is exposed for needs such as mine and I haven't found it yet.

Comment: I hope my answer can help you

Answer (score 1):

I really think that you don't need `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`. There is an easy way to solve your requirements and the solution don't have problems with the cursor.

You should add this line of code in your `viewDidLoad` (`self.textField` is your `UITextField`):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(shortcut:) name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:self.textField];
```

then, you should add the selector, e.g.:

```
- (void) shortcut: (NSNotification*) notification
{
    UITextField *notificationTextField = [notification object];

    if (notificationTextField == self.textField)
    {
        [self checkDoubleA:notificationTextField];
        [self checkDoubleAB:notificationTextField];
        [self checkDoubleSpace:notificationTextField];
    }
}
```

Then you only need to add the 3 methods to check your shortcuts:

```
-(void) checkDoubleA: (UITextField*) textField
{
    NSMutableString *string =  [textField.text mutableCopy];
    NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:@"aa"];
    if (range.location == NSNotFound)
    {
        NSLog(@"string was not found");
    }
    else
    {
        [string replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:@"ä"];
    }
    textField.text = string;
}

-(void) checkDoubleAB: (UITextField*) textField
{
    NSMutableString *string =  [textField.text mutableCopy];
    NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:@"ab"];
    if (range.location == NSNotFound)
    {
        NSLog(@"string was not found");
    }
    else
    {
        [string replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:@"XYZ"];
    }
    textField.text = string;
}

- (void) checkDoubleSpace: (UITextField*) textField
{
    NSMutableString *string =  [textField.text mutableCopy];
    NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:@"  "];
    if (range.location == NSNotFound)
    {
        NSLog(@"String was not found");
    }
    else
    {
        [string replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:@" "];
    }
    textField.text = string;
}
```

You can download a demo of this code [here](https://github.com/GabrielMassana/UITextField_Shortcut).

Comment: Thanks for making the effort, but your solution has the same problem that I tried to explain for mine: If you move the text cursor to the left, e.g. between other chars, typing will reset the cursor to the end of the input line because that's what setting textField.text does. (Also, good idea to put it right on github, though if you don't implement the code/nib for iPad, you shouldn't include it, as one may wonder why nothing happens :)

Comment: @ThomasTempelmann what is your problem then. My solution do not have problems with the cursos because is checking while tipping. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: The challenge is to make sure that the user can still edit text that he has typed, i.e. go back and insert text that then gets also expanded. To make that work, the cursor position needs to be carefully adjusted after every shortcut replacement, and I was wondering if there is a way that doesn't require me saving and updating the selection range myself, but that it rather comes automagically when I replace part of the typed text.

Comment: @ThomasTempelmann I've got now your problem. Sure, if you want to kept the cursor in position you should do it manually with the `NSRange`. I'm sure it's a small method. Anyway, `[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]` `UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification` it is a better approach than the delegate.

Comment: Thanks, I'll consider using your code path as I agree that it's the better place to do the text replacement. Won't give you the checkmark though because it's not really answering my question. Still, I appreciate the effort and advice.